# Is there a common convension to put new methods(on top or on bottom)?

Tags: coding-style

If we omit visibility modifiers(let's say all methods are public), is there any common convension to put new methods in class? I mean if I put them on bottom it's logically correct, because methods are sorted by date. If I put them on top, it's easy to see and compare what methods are added if the class is very long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just depends on what you and your team are comfortable with. I usually have method at the top of my class followed by fields. If there are many method that do different thing you are better off organizing them in a new class. Now without seeing any code I'm simply guessing.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is.
As Kalagen said it's up to you and your team to decide it.

I would keep any methods that share similar functionality together and keep the class definition short.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer in my opinion is no. Coding style might vary depending on the language you are using and the team you are working with. In addition you might have your own preference as well. I tend to add new methods close to methods that are related to it (e.g. if `method1` calls `method2` then  `method1` is above `method2`). Then it is relatively easy to find the method that's being called. On the other hand, most IDEs can find the method with a mouse click.

If you're using version control, you can easily see what methods were added and in which order, so sorting by date is not needed.

And as others have mentioned, keep the class small. Take a look at [the Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). If the methods you are adding are not related to the responsibility of the class, extract them and create a new class.